# Комбинация mixin-ов, которые передаются через аргумент другого mixin-а и вызываются поочередно

Tags: scss

возможно ли что то такое в sass

```
@mixin combined($options, $mixins) {
  @each $value in $mixins {
    //value === имя михина из области видимости
    // 1:
    @include #{$value}($options);
    //либо как то так
    // value и есть михин
    // 2:
    $value($options);
    //либо как то еще
  }
}

//приминение
// 1:
$options: (...);
$mixinNames: 'a', 'b';
combined($options, $mixinNames);

// 2:
$mixins: @include a, @include b;
combined($options, $mixins);
```

Comment: интересно, надо будет попробовать, не уверен, но кто знает)